# When I type a 2 it becomes a 3

Tags: laptop, keyboard, numpad

Can anyone tell me why whenever I type a 2, even using the numeric keyboard, it comes out as a 3?

If I type 28 and then delete the 8 it changes to a 3. It started in email and now it's in Excel as well. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally re-mapped a key. What OS, what make and model of computer might help tell how to un-map it.

Comment: What operating system? Does it happen with both the built-in and external keyboards? (I'm guessing, since you said it happens with the numeric keypad, but some 17" behemoths actually have an integrated numeric keypad, so...) Have you installed any new software lately? Like something offering to do a free scan of your system for viruses? ;-)

Comment: *"If I type 28 and then delete the 8 it changes to a 3."* You mean before you delete the 8, it's a 2, but when you delete the 8 it's a 3? That doesn't quite jibe with the first sentence in your question, which says you can't even type a 2.

Comment: Try the onscreen keyboard and see if the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different programs that are typing aids.  You can set them to do things like replace nme with your full name.  If it changes the 2 to a 3 only after deleting the 8 it sounds like one of these programs was accidentally set to replace 2s with 3s.  If you do not knowingly have software on your computer for this purpose it could be a virus or a friend/family/co-worker practical joke.